# iOS file downloading

Tags: iphone, ios, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS download and save image inside app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238139/ios-download-and-save-image-inside-app)

I want to download a file. I found this

`[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://lasp.colorado.edu/home/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/suncombo1.jpg"]]`

My questions are:

1. Where does the file saved?
2. By using threads, is it any possible to build a status bar for downloads?
3. Are there any way to change the memory(internal/external) to save the file?

Now I am using

`NSData *dataImage = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://lasp.colorado.edu/home/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/suncombo1.jpg"]];
    downloadStatus.text =@"size: %zd", malloc_size(dataImage);`

The result is always 32. Shouldn't that be the size of the actual image?

Comment: how come you couldn't find any documentation ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238139/ios-download-and-save-image-inside-app

Answer (score 1):

1. The file is not saved. It's loaded/retrieved and converted into an `NSData` object.
2. Yes. However, if you're doing this you should look at `NSURLConnection` and particularly the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` protocol. You'll need to asynchronously download the file and get the callbacks into the delegate to be able to update your status bar. Or you could use a 3rd party networking library to simplify the whole thing, but it's good to understand what's going on behind the scenes.
3. Yes. You can save the `NSData` object as a file when it's downloaded. If you were using Cocoa (not iOS) you could use `NSURLDownload` to download the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:myProgressIndicator];
[request startSynchronous];
NSLog(@"Max: %f, Value: %f", [myProgressIndicator maxValue],[myProgressIndicator doubleValue]);
```

And you can also follow this link to make more underastanding :)
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: I recommend using `AFNetworking` instead of ASI libraries, because they're no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the downloaded data to a variable and show it in an UIImageView as follows.

```
NSData *dataImage = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://lasp.colorado.edu/home/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/suncombo1.jpg"]];
self.imageViewYours.image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataImage];
```

Comment: it simply cannot find imageViewYours property

Comment: I just mentioned it as an example. You use this code according to your usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code Worked for Me.  The Image will save to your PhotoAlbum.

```
   -(IBAction)save_Image:(id)sender
    {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your URL"]]]], self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(imageDownloaded) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO ];

    }

- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if (error != NULL)
    {
        // handle error
    }
    else
    {
        // handle ok status
    }
}

- (void)imageDownloaded
{

      // network animation off
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;



    // do whatever you need to do after
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new to Obj-C, I'd first get familiar with NSURLConnection and NSURLConnectionDataDelegate (protocol). Once you feel comfortable that you know what's going on, you can easily switch to a networking library such as AFNetworking to simplify things.