# Download images from web and save on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, image, core-data, store, nsuserdefaults

I have to download images from web and save them on iPhone and then use that images for views. Main problem is: how should I save that images on iPhone ? Which method should I use ? NSUserDefaults, CoreData ?

HELP!! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the file like this:

```
 NSData *data1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
        [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:data1 attributes:nil];

        if (image==nil) {
            NSLog(@"Not Saved...:%@",name);
        }
```

Comment: Ohh tnx alot. And how do I retrieve that same data ? Anyway, which method is that, do I need to add any frameworks or something ?

Comment: Also one more thing. When user downloads info from web, he gets image, images origin, and some other info. How can I store all that and to know which info belongs to which image ? Should I use NSDictionary and store as keys - image, origin, info, and then store dictionaryies to NSMutableArray, and than store NSMutableArray to filemanager ?

Comment: You can store NSDictionary with the name of the file as the key, and a NSArray with that info, for example.

Comment: Dunno how exactly do you mean. Lets say I have NSString *info, and NSData *data (image). How can i store that pair on device ? Tnx.

Comment: Well, for example you can store a dictionary where the key is info, and the object is data, and store it in a NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 1):

This Question might be helpful to you. It explains both the steps you have mentioned.

[iOS download and save image inside app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238139/ios-download-and-save-image-inside-app)