# Make UIImageView use parsed photos to animate

Tags: ios, json, uiimageview, nsarray, animated

I want to use `photos` I parse from `my API` to make an `UIImageView` animate.

I get an the `urls of the photos in an array` but I can't figure out how to download the photos, `put them in an array and then in the image view.`

Could anyone help me with this? I can't figure it out :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download them using NSData method : initWithContentsOfURL:options:error, then create an UIImage from this NSData.

After you download all the images, and you have an array of UIImage, set the animationImages property of the UIImageView with that Array.

Of course, download the images in a thread so you won't block the UI.

Comment: +1 for **Of course, download the images in a thread so you won't block the UI**

Comment: But I they all have different urls?

Comment: You need to run on those URLs in a for loop, and download each one of them in a thread. in the end of the download add them to the array (In the main thread of course). When the number of images in the array reach the number of urls, you know you downloaded all the images, and then you can add it to the image view (Again, in the main thread).

Answer (score 0):

To add image to imageview from a url the solution is straightforwared:

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:theURL];
```

For lot of images thought it is better to load them asynchronously and use image caching. There are many open source libraries for this like SDWebImage.

Answer (score 0):

use this [download images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238139/ios-download-and-save-image-inside-app)

or use AFNetworking library [link](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for downloading images. download the library and add AFNetworking folder  to your project. Add required frameworks(Security, MobileCoreServices and SystemConfiguration) and use the AFImageRequestOperation class.

Use this code to download images

```
    -(void)downloadImage:(NSString *)imageUrl {

    // download the photo

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];
    AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation
                                          imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                          imageProcessingBlock:nil
                                          success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
                                          {
                                              if (image != nil) {
                                                  NSLog(@"image downloaded %@", image);
                                                  [self.imageArray addObject:image];
                                              }

                                             //put code to add image to image view here 
                                          } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                              NSLog(@" error %@", error.description);

                                          }];

    [operation start];


}
```