# xcode5: how can I save and load an image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, gpuimage

I'm developing an app, where I can apply filters on an image.
 I want to create an undo button which resets the original image in the `imageView`.
The solution is that I just save the original image in it's own `UIImage` object before I apply any filters to it. This way I can just go back to that in my undo method.

Does somebody know how I can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS download and save image inside app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238139/ios-download-and-save-image-inside-app)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html

You can do what you want with `UIImagePNGRepresentation()`.

Then to re-read: `imageWithContentsOfFile:`

Answer (score 0):

`Get Image from disk` . Suppose `image stored` in `document directory`.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *yourImgPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.png"];

UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:yourImgPath];
```

Create `tempImage` from `originalImage`

```
UIImage *tempImage = originalImage;
```

`Appy filters on tempImage`

**EDIT** : How to `save` then below is `method` to save in `document directory`.

```
- (BOOL)saveImageInDocDir:(UIImage *)image withImagename:(NSString *)strImgName {
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:strImgName];
  NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
  BOOL isSaved = [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];   
  return isSaved;
}
```

You can also use `NSTempraryDirectory` to `save images` as its safe from `cloud backup`