# Swift callback inline function usage

Tags: swift, callback

Using Swift I can do a callback like the following:

```
userService.validateToken("6beba35f", success: onSuccess, failure: onFailure)

func onSuccess(status_code: Int, data: String)
{
    var dd : String = ""
}

func onFailure(status_code: Int, data: String)
{
    var dd : String = ""

}
```

but i would like to have the functions on the same line as the call:

Example 1:

```
userService.validateToken("6beba35f",
        success: (Int, String) -> ()
            {
        },
        failure: (Int, String) -> ()
            {
    })
```

Example 2:

```
userService.validateToken("6beba35f",
        success: (Int, String)
            {
        },
        failure: (Int, String)
            {
        })
```

both give errors.  I think im close with Example 1 but it keeps giving me an error "Expected , seperator" and when i have it add the ","

`success: (Int, String), -> ()`
but the error keeps saying "Expected , separator"

Any ideas on what the solutions is?

**Including function**

```
func validateToken(token: String, success: (Int, String) -> Void, failure: (Int, String) -> Void)
{
    if(Network.isOnline())
    {
        var url: String = Commons.plistValue("Base URL") + "/security/" + token

        Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
            .responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in

                let jsonData: JSON = JSON(json!)
                let statusCode: Int = response!.statusCode

                if(statusCode == 202)
                {
                    success(statusCode, jsonData["status"]["message"].stringValue)
                }
                else
                {
                    failure(statusCode, jsonData["status"]["message"].stringValue)
                }
            }
    }
    else
    {
        failure(-1, "No Internet Connection")
    }

}
```

**Usage Fix**

```
    userService.validateToken("6beba35f",
        success: { status_code, data in
            (
                println(status_code)
            )

        },
        failure: { status_code, data in
            (
                println(status_code)
            )
    })
```

Comment: I included the validateToken function

Comment: Have you tried `{ status_code, data in (code here) }` ?

Comment: OMG your the man.  Thanks so much

Comment: zneak maybe change your comment to be an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [several ways](http://goshdarnclosuresyntax.com) to declare or use closures. The simplest one you're looking for is probably:

```
{ status_code, data in
    println(status_code)
}
```

This needs to be used in such a way that the compiler can infer the type of `status_code`, `data`, and determine that there should be no return value. For instance, you can pass it as a function parameter (what you want), or assign it to a variable with appropriate type hints.

Comment: Thank you for the link also helps tons :)

Comment: I have a similar question here I'm still trying to figure out, it has an open bounty if anyone wants to take a stab at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29871633/how-would-i-create-a-callback-around-an-xml-request