# iOS download an mp3 to use later on in an app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch

Is it possible for me to download an mp3 from a website so I can use it later on in my app, *without blocking the rest of my app's execution*?

All I keep finding are synchronous ways of doing this.

I would like to cache the mp3's in an array. I will only be getting 5 or 6 short clips at the most.

Can anyone help?

Comment: a bit like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238139/ios-download-and-save-image-inside-app but with mp3's and asynchronously

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You can use a `NSURLConnection` and save the received data into a temporary NSData variable, and when done, write it to disk.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    _mutableData = [NSMutableData new];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    if (_mutableData) {
        [_mutableData appendData:data];
    }
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    dispatch_queue_t bgGlobalQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
    dispatch_async(bgGlobalQueue, {
        [_mutableData writeToFile:_filePath atomically:YES];
    });
}
```

Note: you should add all the corresponding error handling to the above code, do not use it "as is".

You can then create a `NSURL` with the file path and use that URL to play the mp3 file.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:_filePath];
```

Answer (score 5):

The most modern way is to use NSURLSession. It had built in download functionality. Use an `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` for this.

**Swift**

```
let url = NSURL(string:"http://example.com/file.mp3")!

let task =  NSURLSession.sharedSession().downloadTaskWithURL(url) { fileURL, response, error in
    // fileURL is the URL of the downloaded file in a temporary location.
    // You must move this to a location of your choosing
}

task.resume()
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/file.mp3"];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] downloadTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSURL *fileURL, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // fileURL is the URL of the downloaded file in a temporary location.
    // You must move this to a location of your choosing
}];

[task resume];
```