# Get image URL from webpage

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I am trying to get the image from this website, but I am having a hard time. All I need is the URL of the image, when I print the URL I get noting back. This is the URL and I am trying to get the main image seen in the middle, http://theoldrussuanbum.vsco.co/media/555722fde555153e3e8b4591

I have been trying the following code with no luck.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:_urlTextField.text];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:URL completionHandler:
  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
      NSString *contentType = nil;
      if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
          NSDictionary *headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];


          contentType = headers[@"Content-Type"];
      }
      HTMLDocument *document = [HTMLDocument documentWithData:data
                                        contentTypeHeader:contentType];

      HTMLElement *element = [document firstNodeMatchingSelector:@"img"];

      NSString *urlString = element.attributes[@"src"];

      NSLog(@"URL: %@", urlString);

  }] resume];
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you checked the value of error in the response block?

Comment: The question is really about parsing HTML, and only incidentally about that you're hunting for an image tag within it.  Maybe the library isn't working as advertised?  You could try converting the NSData to a string (ala http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring), and then feed the string to the `documentWithString:` constructor.  It might work better since it's cited in the doc (the author might have tested it).

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions to first
find the start with the regular expression: `@"twitter:image\"\\s+content=\""`
and then
extract the URL with the regular expression: `@"[^>]+"`

You can find information of regular expression syntax at the ICU User Guide: [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp).

Example code:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://theoldrussuanbum.vsco.co/media/555722fde555153e3e8b4591";
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *sessionTask;
sessionTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:URL completionHandler:
               ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                   NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                   NSRange preambleRange = [html rangeOfString:@"twitter:image\"\\s+content=\"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
                   if (preambleRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                       NSString *htmlOffset = [html substringFromIndex:preambleRange.location + preambleRange.length];
                       NSRange imgUrlRange = [htmlOffset rangeOfString:@"[^>]+" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
                       if (imgUrlRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                           NSString *imgURLString = [htmlOffset substringWithRange:imgUrlRange];
                           NSLog(@"URL: %@", imgURLString);
                       }
                   }

               }];
[sessionTask resume];
```

Output:

> URL: http://image.vsco.co/1/548c6a64020e11517164/555722fde555153e3e8b4591/600x800/vsco_051615.jpg"

Of course production code must handle all errors which this example code does  not.

Comment: This code is good but not working for All web URL. So please do you have any new solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think first thing you need to do is provide actual url of image resource.

For example; http://image.vsco.co/1/548c6a64020e11517164/548c7b532b5615b6658b4567/vsco_121314.jpg

This is what I get from page source of that web page

And then just refer this question;

[iOS download and save image inside app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238139/ios-download-and-save-image-inside-app)

Comment: I am trying to find the URL by using the method above, then I'll create a `UIImage` from the URL of the image.