# How to Load image very fast if image is big size in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have big image it came from Api then how to load it fast . It Take too much time to load

```
  let data = NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string: self.imageFile)! as URL)

            if data == nil{
            }

            else{

                DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.imageShow.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
                }
            }
```

this is my code can any one suggest me

Comment: **Never ever** load data synchronously from a remote `URL` with `Data(contentsOf`. Use asynchronous `URLSession` or similar API. And don't use `NSURL / NSData` in Swift 3+

Comment: use SDWebImage library for loading images even big and can cache it too.

Comment: Comments/answers saying about thread - it's not yet clear if code running on main thread, maybe it's already running asynchronously, if no, then you have to change it. Also things like `NSURL(string: self.imageFile)!` are very dangerous, you should learn basic stuff like optionals, networking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use this code to Async Download Image.**

```
    if let url = self.imageFile{

    let url = URL(string: self.imageFile)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

            /**CHECK 404 HERE*/
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode == 400 {
                    //YOUR CODE HERE
                return
                }
            }


            DispatchQueue.main.async() {    // execute on main thread
                self.imageShow.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }

    task.resume()

    }else{

        DispatchQueue.main.async() {    // execute on main thread
         self.viewImageType.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

BETTER NOT TO DEPEND ON THIRD PARTY LIBRARIES

Comment: and how can i call this

Comment: @Anurag Mishra Just replace the code. You need to add a progress view to show the network activity.

Comment: @Anurag Mishra Please have a look to updated answer.

Comment: it is also taking time my image is big

Comment: If your image is Big then it is not possible to download it without fast internet connection. What I have shared is a async download code. Which will not stuck your UI. Better to keep thumbnail image or small image at server. Thanks. @Anurag Mishra

Comment: @Anurag Mishra If you use code shared by me would do same: download image and then show

Comment: Can you suggest me how to download image but not in phone

Comment: You can create background task to download in background and store it in document directory. And then use it whenever you want to show it on view.

Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238139/ios-download-and-save-image-inside-app

Comment: this error are coming when i call httpResponse.statusCode == 400      UIView.hidden must be used from main thread only   
   self.viewImageType.isHidden = true

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSOperationQueue` to load your image on background thread and then load image on image view on main thread. You can achieve this by:

```
    let myQueue = OperationQueue()
    myQueue.addOperation { // Load image on background thread
        if let urlString = URL(string: self.imageFile) {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: urlString)
                DispatchQueue.main.async { // Load image on main thread
                    self.imageShow.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            } catch {
                print("not able to load image")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to call if there is 404 url also

Comment: I am getting your point as like image is not present at given url. In that case `let data = try Data(contentsOf: urlString)` will throw it in catch block and you can assign a default image there

Comment: it is also taking time to load my image file is big